# make responsive jquery slimbox2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, user-interface

i have a site with this script (http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2/), this is not responsive , so i decided to make responsive, i have used this code

```
#lbCenter { height: auto!important;
  width: 80%!important;
  margin-left: -41%!important;
  left: 50%!important;
}

#lbBottomContainer {left: 50%!important;
  width: 80%!important;
  margin-left: -41%!important;
}

#lbImage {
  background-size: 100% 100%!important;
  width: 100%!important;
}
```

after this the box is responsive , but only for width, not for height ,
if use height:auto; on #lbCenter the photo disappear.

how fix ??

you an view the demo on the link of official site.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try height: 100% ? Maybe you can send us a link of the site you are using this plugin on?

Comment: yes, when use 100%  the white background overlay the full page so it's not good, this is on a private area of site so not show the site, but it's same of demo site page